# What's the meaning ${1:-}?

Tags: bash

Could you help me explain the expression in BASH script ?

```
${1:-}
```

I never see it before, so I try some about it.

```
echo ${1:-}
echo ${1}
```

I cant see any difference.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: My English is poor ,so I can't find the keyword in Bash Manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a small example adapted from [here](http://wuhrr.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/bash-shell-scripting-a-colon-difference/)

```
varName="Aloha"
echo "varName is not empty: the two constructs behave the same"
echo ${varName-Hello World}
echo ${varName:-Hello World}
echo ""
unset varName
echo "varName is unset: they still behave the same way"
echo ${varName-Hello World}
echo ${varName:-Hello World}
echo ""
varName=""
echo "varName is empty: this is where the two differs"
echo ${varName-Hello World}
echo ${varName:-Hello World}
echo ""
```

Basically `:-` changes the values of the variable if it's empty or not set, and `:` changes it if it's not set.

Answer (score 2):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> ${parameter:-word}
>
> Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is 
>   substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

Comment: +1 for linking to the documentation, though frankly I prefer the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), which is more organized and easier to navigate.  This feature in particular falls under [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have much purpose. `${1-}` is relevant when `set -u` is enabled, in which case it's another hack similar to `${1+"$1"}` to prevent throwing errors in the event a parameter with a value that is expected to be possibly unset is dereferenced.

```
 $ ( f() { printf '<%s> <%s>\n' $# ${1-}; }; set -u; f )
<0> <>
 $ ( f() { printf '<%s> <%s>\n' $# $1; }; set -u; f )
-bash: $1: unbound variable
```

Adding the colon will expand the alternate when the parameter is unset or null. In either case, when the expansion is unquoted the result will always be no args (regardless of the IFS value). It isn't uncommon for people to be unaware of the difference between the `-` and `:-` PE operators due to the unfortunate way it's specified in Bash's manpage.

As usual, I suggest never using `set -u` in scripts. Use it only temporarily if you're one of those that find it useful for debugging.

Comment: Thank you. But it a little difficut for me.